# Error: ENOENT - Program node server.js exited with code 8

Tags: node.js, openshift

Having a tough time with this one.  While running my node app on OpenShift, on a request I get:

```
GET / 200 112.394 ms - -
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/var/lib/openshift/53b9410ce0b8cdd72900006b/app-root/runtime/repo/public/system/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

Couple things:

- The app works fine locally.
- Node restarts after the error, but continues to get the error on follow up requests.
- When I ssh to my account, the /var/lib/openshift/53b9410ce0b8cdd72900006b/app-root/runtime/repo/public/system/lib directory does not exist.
- Earlier, I ran out of space, purchased additional space.  Wondering if I somehow need to do a clean install?

Any ideas?   Thanks much!

Comment: Have you fixed this ?